# How do i make it to check if there is a same tags name already exist?

Tags: sqlite, discord, discord.py

I created a custom commands, more like custom tags commands but i wanted to make it check, if there is same tags name send a message that the tags with this name was already exist
I tried with this code, but it keeps logging the new tags into sqlite although its already exist.

```
    @tags.command()
    async def create(self, ctx, tag=None, *,text=None):
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT text FROM tags WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} and tag")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            sql = (f"INSERT INTO tags(guild_id, tag, text) VALUES(?,?,?)")
            val = (ctx.guild.id, tag, text)
            await ctx.send(f'Created {tag}!')
            cursor.execute(sql, val)
            db.commit()
        if result is not None:
            await ctx.send(f'Tag named {tag} was already exist.')
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause of your query must include the condition for the column `tag`:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT text FROM tags WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} and tag = {tag}")
```

and maybe there is no need to check for `guild_id`:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT text FROM tags WHERE tag = {tag}")
```

Or by using `?` placeholder:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT text FROM tags WHERE tag = ?", (tag,))
```

Comment: It's you again , anyway the first option was working, also I need to check the guild_id because of the tags was used per guilds